# Replace string in system path with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, path, set

I need to change **C:\Program Files (x86)** in **C:\Progra~2** in the system path variable. I was thinking to do this with Powershell, so I came up with the following script.

```
$NewPath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).Path

$OldValue = ${Program Files (x86)}
$NewValue = "Progra~2"

$NewPath = $NewPath -replace $OldValue, $NewValue

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH –Value $newPath

$NewPath
```

The output is unfortunately not what I expected.

```
Progra~2oProgra~2mProgra~2eProgra~21Progra~2\Progra~2oProgra~2pProgra~2mProgra~2nProgra~2\Progra~2bProgra~2iProgra~2nProgra~2;Progra~2CProgra~2:
Progra~2\Progra~2OProgra~2rProgra~2aProgra~2cProgra~2lProgra~2eProgra~2\Progra~2MProgra~2iProgra~2dProgra~2dProgra~2lProgra~2eProgra~2wProgra~2a
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: `$OldValue=${Pogram Files (x86)}` -> `$OldValue = "Program Files (x86)"` ?

Comment: I initially was using that value but that didn't work because of the (). I had to use ${} because () was interpeted as part of a command.

Comment: Ah yes, `-replace` uses regular expressions, you have to escape the parens: `$OldValue = "Program Files \(x86\)"`.

Comment: Bingo, that did the trick! thank's a lot

Comment: @sodawillow Please write that up as an answer, so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$OldValue = ${Program Files (x86)}
```

should be replaced by

```
$OldValue = "Program Files \(x86\)"
```

Backslashes `\` escape the parens interpreted as a `regex` by `-replace`